# open PDF when form submits

Tags: jquery, forms, popup, submit

Is there a way to have a 'submit' button on a form open a PDF (in a browser window like normal) as well as submitting the form?

Is there some jQuery I could add in using the button class of the submit button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try adding `onclick="yourFxnToOpenPdf()"` to your button

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is a bit weird, but I think you can try this:

**JavaScript**

```
$(function () {
  $('form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('http://react-etc.net/files/typescript-book/typescript.pdf', '_blank');
    this.submit();
  });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form method="#" action="#">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yep, I know its weird. ...its a client request. :/ Thanks for this, i'll give it a try.